# Angular2-materialize carousel load before service angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I use router with params of category, my router-link pass category from url to my service load data from category, but when i click in other category my carousel loads empty before new data.
my data.

My service:

```
getWine(id): Observable<IWine> {
  return this.http.get<IWine>('http://localhost:8888/example/getWines/' + id);
}
```

My component:

```
export class WinesComponent implements OnInit {


public Wines;



constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private _dataService: WineService, private http: HttpClient) {
}

ngOnInit() {
   this.Wines = this.route.paramMap.pipe(
   switchMap((params: ParamMap) =>
   this._dataService.getWine(+params.get('id'))
));
}

}
```

My view component:

```
<div materialize="carousel" [materializeParams]="[{padding: 150}]" class="carousel center">
  <a *ngFor="let wines of Wines | async" class="modal-trigger carousel-item wine " (tap)="openModal()" >
      <img src="assets/images/vinho.png">
      <h2>{{wines.name}}</h2>
      <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
  </a>
</div>
```

I need to load the carousel after receiving the data

Comment: Can you explain the issue?

Comment: the carousel loads before loading the service data, showing nothing on the screen

Comment: can you provide more of your component & your service ?

Comment: my component is only it, and my service only request to my api

Comment: post the all of the component, to see the Wines property and the constructor mainly !

Comment: question edited

Answer (score 0):

it feels like the expected behavior, if you want to hide the caroussel while the data is loaded from the service, you can use ngIf :

```
<div materialize="carousel" *ngIf="wines.length" [materializeParams]="[{padding: 150}]" class="carousel center">
  <a *ngFor="let wine of wines" class="modal-trigger carousel-item wine " (tap)="openModal()" >
    <img src="assets/images/vinho.png">
    <h2>{{wine.name}}</h2>
    <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
 </a>
</div>
```

Your component :

```
export class WinesComponent implements OnInit {


   public wines = [];



   constructor(
      private route: ActivatedRoute,
      private _dataService: WineService,
      private http: HttpClient) {
   }

   ngOnInit() {
      this.route.paramMap.pipe(
          switchMap((params: ParamMap) => {
             this._dataService.getWine(+params.get('id')).subscribe((wines) => {
                  this.wines = wines;
              })
             }
           ));
    }

}
```

Try this, i hope it helps